# Cравнение элементов списка с соседними элементами Python

Tags: python, сравнение

не как не могу решить задачу есть сгенерированный список.

```
from itertools import product
from  more_itertools import unique_everseen

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [11,12,13,14,15]
c = [21,22,23,24,25]
d = [31,32,33,34,35]
e = [41,42,43,44,45]

f = [45,44,43,42,41]

result = []
for subset in product(a, b, c, d, e, f):
  x = list(unique_everseen(subset))
  if len(x) == 6:
     result.append(x)

for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Сейчас список выглядит так, тобишь повторяет 3 и более цифры в одной комбинации....

```
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 45]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 44]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 43]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 42]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 42, 45]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 42, 44]
......
..........
[5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 44]
[5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 43]
[5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 42]
[5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 41]
12500 комбинаций.
```

Суть задачи такая чтобы из уже имеющего списка (result) получить совершено разные комбинации и при условии что в каждой комбинации не будет повторяться 3 одинаковые цифры , также порядок списка должен остаться прежним..... Я думаю нужно каким то образом отсортировать полученные данные а вот как это сделать не могу придумать

Я хочу получить примерно такой результат:

```
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 45]    [1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 45]
[2, 12, 22, 32, 41, 44]    [2, 11, 21, 32, 41, 44]  
[3, 13, 23, 33, 41, 43]    [3, 11, 23, 33, 41, 43]
[4, 14, 24, 34, 41, 42]    [4, 14, 21, 31, 41, 42]
[5, 15, 25, 35, 42, 45]    [5, 11, 21, 35, 42, 45]
[6, 16, 26, 36, 42, 44]    [6, 12, 21, 32, 42, 44]
```

Comment: поясните что в итоге вы хотите получить, приведите пример.

Comment: Я немного изменил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста где написано:
<Я хочу получить примерно такой результат>

Comment: Нужно получить из списка тот что имееться (result) все возможные комбинации только при условии что в одной комбинации не будут повторяться цифры больше 3 раз.

Comment: а нельзя перемешать с последними списками?

Comment: Суть задачи такая чтобы из уже имеющего списка (result) получить совершено разные комбинации и при условии что в каждой комбинации не будет повторяться 3 одинаковые цифры , также порядок списка должен остаться прежним..... Я думаю нужно каким то образом отсортировать полученные данные а вот как это сделать не могу придумать......

Comment: Можно поиграться на меньших списках чтобы нагляднее было.

Comment: можете хоть мини пример привести пожалуйста? в какую сторону капать?

Comment: a `f` у вас точно есть? в предыдущем вопросе его нет. По значениям он должен совпадать с `е`, все верно?

Comment: cейчас посмотрю что можно сделать.

Comment: Да верно, буду очень признателен если немного раскроете карты))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что если таким образом:

```py
from itertools import product

m = [[*range(1+i*10,1+i*10+5)] for i in range(5)]
m.append([*range(45,40,-1)])

*result, = product(*m)
len_m = len(m) * len(m) * len(m) + 1

for b in range(len_m):
    for i in result[b::len_m]:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Огромное огромное вам спасибо) то что нужно)

Comment: Спасибо еще раз огромнейшее мне очень понравился ваш код и стиль его написания.
Я новичок в Python и в программирование  в общем, какие вы можете мне посоветовать
учебные материалы чтобы я мог писать такой же код как у вас?
Спасибо.

Comment: @РобинГут, мой код не идеален. Учебных материалов предостаточно в инете, выбирайте те, что можете усвоить, все зависит от вашего уровня. И больше пишите код.

Answer (score 0):

Импорты тут лишние

```
    res=[]
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    b = [11,12,13,14,15]
    c = [21,22,23,24,25]
    d = [31,32,33,34,35]
    e = [41,42,43,44,45]
    f = [45,44,43,42,41]
    for i in (a,b,c,d,e,f):
        res.append(i)
    for i in res:
        print(i)#или print(*i)
```

Comment: спасибо, только мне нужно отсортировать список именно тех сгенерированых комбинаций который сделал subset  > product

Comment: Чтобы не был вывод как сейчас:
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 45]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 44]
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 43]

Я жду такой результат:
[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 45]
[2, 12, 22, 31, 41, 44]
[3, 13, 22, 31, 41, 43]

Comment: Сорян, не так прочитал)) unique_everseen удаляет соседние элементы списка, т, е из списка list(‘aaassdAssd’) он сделает list(‘asdAsd’), a product создает все возможные комбинации из значений в списках, в данном случае их будет 15625. Хотелось бы тогда задание услышать

Comment: Нужно получить из списка тот что имееться (result) все возможные комбинации только при условии что в одной комбинации не будут повторяться цифры больше 3 раз.